# How do I add two integers represented as two non-empty linked lists?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Question: You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and 
 return it as a linked list. You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except 0 itself **

Example: 
    Working testcase is as follows:
 - Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
 - Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8
 - Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.

My solution is not working for the following testcase:

- Input:

  - [9]
  - [1,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]
- Output: [0,-4,-6,-3,-8,-4,-7,-4,-1,-2]
- Expected: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

Definition for singly-linked list:

```
public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}
```

This is my solution

```
import java.lang.Math;

class Solution 
{

public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) 
{
        int count = 0;
        int number1=0;
        int number2=0;
        int temp=0;

        while(l1 !=null)
        {
            temp = l1.val;
            number1 += temp*Math.pow(10,count);
            count++;
            l1= l1.next;
         }

        count = 0;

        while(l2 !=null)
        {
            temp = l2.val;
            number2 += temp*Math.pow(10,count);
            count++;
            l2= l2.next;
        }

        int sum = number1 + number2;
        ListNode l3 = new ListNode(sum%10);
        ListNode l4 = l3;

        while(sum!=0)
        {
          sum=sum/10;
          if (sum!=0) 
          {
          l3.next = new ListNode(sum%10);
          l3=l3.next; 
          } 

        }
        return l4;  

 }
}
```

Comment: OK, but what is your question?

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: This is really not the right way to solve this problem.

Comment: I am given two ListNode (implementation is as follows) like single linked list each containing digits in reverse order. I have to add both the numbers from both List Node by using them in their actual order. My code is working fine for all testcases except one.

    Input:
        [9]
        [1,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]
    Output: [0,-4,-6,-3,-8,-4,-7,-4,-1,-2]
    Expected: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

Answer (score 2):

You have integer overflow. `[1,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]` should represent the number 9 999 999 991. You are trying to convert the list to an `int` (`number1`), but the largest number that an `int` can hold is 2 147 483 647 because an `int` is a signed 2-complement 32 bit integer.

In this situation it would have been really nice if Java would throw an exception to make us aware why it doesn’t work. No such luck. Instead it simply throws away the high-order bits exceeding 32 bits, giving some nonsense negative value (negative because the sign bit (the first bit) happens to be 1).

So what you need to do is perform the addition directly as linked lists without converting to `int` and back. You can very comfortably have three linked lists each containing up to 11 elements (and also up to a million elements if you needed that), so this will cause no overflow.

If you don’t know what numeric overflow is, please look it up. Your search engine is your friend.

Comment: I have this question on leetcode. I dont know why my output is coming negative Output: [0,-4,-6,-3,-8,-4,-7,-4,-1,-2]

Answer (score 1):

although your logic seems fine, this might run into overflow cases when you encounter large test cases/large numbers represented as a linked lists.

I'll give you a suggestion, don't convert the linked list nodes to a number. There's a way to do it another way around just by normal iteration of linked lists.

Try to think about how you would normally add numbers like the way we were taught in school by writing it down on paper.

Comment: I think it’s a very fine supplement to my answer (or my answer is a modest supplement to yours). Thank you.

Comment: Yes. The same logic but written in a different way.